# Two different machines talk publicly via rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqpstorm

I've set up a rabbitmq server on rackspace host. I've done the (python) tutorials. Now I want to do same 'hello world' tutorials, but instead of connecting to `localhost` with the example scripts, I want to run the `send.py` and `receive.py` on two totally different machines.

I've been reading through the docs, but I don't think I'm seeing how it all fits together. What I thought I might need to do, is add a user:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl add_user xxx yyy
```

I made sure it showed up with a `list_users`

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_users
Listing users ...
guest   [administrator]
xxx []
```

For now I let my `receive.py` run on the server connecting against localhost. But the `send.py`, I moved to a Raspberry like Linux SBC and rewrote using `amqpstorm`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
from amqpstorm import Connection, Message

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def publisher():
    with Connection('abc.def.com', 'xxx', 'yyy') as connection:
        with connection.channel() as channel:
            channel.queue.declare(queue='hello')
            properties = {
                'content_type': 'text/plain',
                'headers': {'key': 'value'}
            }

            message = Message.create(channel, 'Vennlig Hilsen', properties)
            message.publish('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    publisher()
```

That creates the following error:

```
# ./send.py 
DEBUG:amqpstorm.connection:Connection Opening
DEBUG:amqpstorm.channel0:Frame Received: Connection.Start
DEBUG:amqpstorm.channel0:Frame Sent: Connection.StartOk
DEBUG:amqpstorm.channel0:Frame Received: Connection.Tune
DEBUG:amqpstorm.channel0:Frame Sent: Connection.TuneOk
DEBUG:amqpstorm.channel0:Frame Sent: Connection.Open
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xend.py", line 22, in <module>
    publisher()
  File "./xend.py", line 9, in publisher
    with Connection('abc.def.com', 'xxx', 'yay') as connection:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/amqpstorm/connection.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/amqpstorm/connection.py", line 191, in open
    self._wait_for_connection_state(state=Stateful.OPEN)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/amqpstorm/connection.py", line 314, in _wait_for_connection_state
    raise AMQPConnectionError('Connection timed out')
amqpstorm.exception.AMQPConnectionError: Connection timed out
```

It spits out the first 6 DEBUG lines pretty quickly, and then stalls with an eventual timeout error of some sort.

Am I even on the right path? Or barking up the wrong tree? Do I need to do more to configure my user (I didn't do anything other than add it)? Is there somewhere I can see additional logging of the server, other than journalctl?

**UPDATE**

```
$ tail -f /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit\@server5.log

=INFO REPORT==== 18-Oct-2016::15:09:28 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.307.0> (67.158.225.133:32786 -> 23.253.234.130:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 18-Oct-2016::15:09:32 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.307.0> (67.158.225.133:32786 -> 23.253.234.130:5672):
{handshake_error,opening,0,
                 {amqp_error,access_refused,
                             "access to vhost '/' refused for user 'xxx'",
                             'connection.open'}}
```

This tells me that I must need to do something additionally to authorize the `xxx`user?

Comment: This is not a coding error, but a DNS issue. Try doing ```ping abc.dev.com``` on the host you are trying to connect to RabbitMQ from.

Comment: I'm able to ssh into the rackspace host from the remote node. So I don't think it's a DNS issue. I made sure that port 5672 is open the box, so I don't think it's a firewall issue either.

Comment: I have updated the error, I had copied a bad version of pika to the SBC I think.

Comment: If there is latency on the connection its likely caused by the low socket timeout set by default in pika.

Comment: Personally I would try a more stable amqp library, like rabbitpy, or my own amqpstorm.

Comment: I'm game @eandersson. Is it as simple as grab the latest `amqpstorm` directory from github, drop it in my `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` and then figure out how to change the simple send.py to use its interface?

Comment: Sure, you can do that or use pip to install it, e.g. ```pip install amqpstorm```.

Comment: You have a bunch of examples here https://github.com/eandersson/amqpstorm/tree/master/examples

Comment: OK, updated question along amqpstorm lines. pip doesn't fit on this small of an SBC (pip wants a full gcc toolchain)

Comment: Interesting - Do you have anything in the RabbitMQ logs? /var/log/rabbitmq

Comment: You need to set the permissions for that user! Search for set_permissions here https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html

Comment: ```sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions xxx ".*" ".*" ".*"```

Comment: Bingo! You should make that an answer and get some more points... :D

Comment: This was a little confusing haha normally RabbitMQ would fail if you can't authenticate, but unfortunately the permissions does not seem to trigger an actual authentication failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your RabbitMQ logs it looks like you forgot to set the appropriate permissions for your new user.

```
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions my_user ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

If you are using a different virtual host don't forget to set the permissions for that virtual host as well.

```
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p my_virtual_host my_user ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

You can read more about these options in the official documentation [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html).